# Change Android Studio Firebase Account

Tags: firebase, android-studio, firebase-test-lab

I'm trying to run a Firebase Test Lab with a project in Android Studio, but it only shows cloud projects from my personal account in Firebase, no one project from my professional account.

*My firebase-cli is connected to my professional account.

[image: Android Studio Test Run Configuration]

Answer (score 0):

I had to keep only my professional account connected to Android Studio. So i can select projects from it.

[image: Androdi Studio - Google Sign]